# "fullscreenchange" event isn't compatible with every browser (looking for Vanilla Javascript fix)

Tags: javascript, fullscreenchange

I am using the "fullscreenchange" event to apply the css I would like by adding or removing an ID (`#showFullscreen`) that will take dominance over the css already applied to `.fullscreen`.

```
    var fullscreen = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen");

    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function() {
        if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement) {
            fullscreen[0].setAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
        } else if (!document.fullscreenElement || !document.webkitFullscreenElement || !document.mozFullScreenElement || !document.msFullscreenElement) {
            fullscreen[0].removeAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
        }
     });
```

How can I get this code to work across all browsers using vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is described in [this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_fullscreenchange.asp) bij W3Schools, you need to prefix the eventname dependent on the browser.

```js
// Includes an empty string because fullscreenchange without prefix is
// also a valid event we need to listen for
const prefixes = ["", "moz", "webkit", "ms"]
var fullscreen = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen");
var fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || /* Standard syntax */
  document.webkitFullscreenElement || /* Chrome, Safari and Opera syntax */
  document.mozFullScreenElement || /* Firefox syntax */
  document.msFullscreenElement /* IE/Edge syntax */;

prefixes.forEach(function(prefix) {
 document.addEventListener(prefix + "fullscreenchange", function() {
    if (fullscreenElement) {
        fullscreen[0].setAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
    } else if (!document.fullscreenchange) {
        fullscreen[0].removeAttribute("id", "showFullscreen");
    }
 });
});
```